# How to programmatically find the device-width in Phonegap/JQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I need to find the device-width of the mobile device.
Although we can specify the content

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=no" />
```

But i need to programmatically obtain the device width to compute some logic in my application. How can I get the device width?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `viewport` dimensions can be gathered via the `window` object:

```
var viewport = {
    width  : $(window).width(),
    height : $(window).height()
};

//can access dimensions like this:
//viewport.height
```

Though you won't always get perfect results, different devices behave differently and this gives the `viewport` dimensions, not the screen dimensions.

Alternatively you could check the width of a `data-role="page"` element to find the `device-width` (since it's set to `100%` of the `device-width`):

```
var deviceWidth = 0;
$(window).bind('resize', function () {
    deviceWidth = $('[data-role="page"]').first().width();
}).trigger('resize');​​​
```

Comment: Hey jasper i need to get this device width in <body> so that i can place myWidth as like here <div id="placeholder" style="width:myWidth;height:150px"></div>

Comment: @Coder_sLaY Then go with my first example: `$('#placeholder').width($(window).width());`.

Comment: The jquery fiddle is dead now. Can you update your answer so that it will be helpful for future users

Answer (score 18):

Not sure that the solution proposed works as expected. Are you sure you get the real device-width?

I'm using the following code in my app and it works fine:

```
function effectiveDeviceWidth() {
    var deviceWidth = window.orientation == 0 ? window.screen.width : window.screen.height;
    // iOS returns available pixels, Android returns pixels / pixel ratio
    // http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/07/more_about_devi.html
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') >= 0 && window.devicePixelRatio) {
        deviceWidth = deviceWidth / window.devicePixelRatio;
    }
    return deviceWidth;
}
```

Hope it can help someone!

Comment: this a great function. this helped me. but to get the good width for me I reverse  : var deviceWidth = window.orientation == 0 ? window.screen.height : window.screen.width;

Comment: Works great! I also needed to reverse the conditional statement like llyas mentioned and then it works.