# Finding Device width

Tags: javascript

How to find the device width using the view port meta tag.

Also wants to display the device width in the console with

java script.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: you don't find the device width using the view port meta tag. and a simple google search would easily show you how to do it

Comment: @SamuelLiew, device width != browser width

Comment: @SamuelLiew, `screen.width` (the width of the device's screen) vs `window.innerWidth` (the width of the browser window). They shouldn't be the same unless the window is maximized / fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

The `viewport` dimensions can be gotten through the `window` object:

```
var viewport = {
    width  : $(window).width(),
    height : $(window).height()
};

//can access dimensions like this:
//viewport.height
```

Though you won't always get perfect results, different devices behave differently and this gives the `viewport` dimensions, not the screen dimensions.

Refer this [**`post`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477028/how-to-programmatically-find-the-device-width-in-phonegap-jquery-mobile) more details on how to check the width of a `data-role="page"` element to find the `device-width`