# jQuery detect Bootstrap 3 state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap 3, there are 4 states; extra small devices, small devices, medium devices, and large devices. How can I know the website is currently at which state with jQuery? So that I can do some processing like when it is in extra small devices, then run this function.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477028/how-to-programmatically-find-the-device-width-in-phonegap-jquery-mobile

Comment: Thanks. I mean is there any direct access to know from bootstrap instead of detect the width directly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I made some changes to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441456/how-to-detect-which-device-view-youre-on-using-twitter-bootstrap-api) for bootstrap 3, try this"

```
function findBootstrapEnvironment() {
    var envs = ["ExtraSmall", "Small", "Medium", "Large"];
    var envValues = ["xs", "sm", "md", "lg"];

    var $el = $('<div>');
    $el.appendTo($('body'));

    for (var i = envValues.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var envVal = envValues[i];

        $el.addClass('hidden-'+envVal);
        if ($el.is(':hidden')) {
            $el.remove();
            return envs[i]
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You should declare the `$el` and not pollute the global scope.

Answer (score 13):

Following @Khurshid's answer (which works perfectly well) I've written a native JavaScript implementation which is [significantly faster](http://jsperf.com/find-twitter-bootstrap-environment#run):

```
function findBootstrapEnvironment() {
    var envs = ["xs", "sm", "md", "lg"],    
        doc = window.document,
        temp = doc.createElement("div");

    doc.body.appendChild(temp);

    for (var i = envs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var env = envs[i];

        temp.className = "hidden-" + env;

        if (temp.offsetParent === null) {
            doc.body.removeChild(temp);
            return env;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I have to admit that I generally dismissed replacing simply jQuery calls with native as an unnecessary micro-optimization. Definitely didn't anticipate this comparison would show a 90+%  difference in performance.

Comment: Work great, but on IE it seems to always return "xs" :S

Comment: For IE support, I used
`if($(this.dom.temp).is(':hidden')) {
     $(this.dom.temp).remove();
     return env;
}`
instead of 
`if (temp.offsetParent === null) {
    doc.body.removeChild(temp);
     return env;
}`

Comment: To make this code Bootstrap v4 compatible, add "xl" to the 'envs' array and change `temp.className = "hidden-" + env;` to `temp.className = "hidden-" + env + "-up";`

Comment: @dburdan Without sounding lazy, I'm quite happy for you to edit my solution and attach your name to it.

Answer (score 6):

I had to do something similiar for the medium size.

The media query for the extra small is up to 480px;

so you can say something like:

```
if($(document).width > 480)
{

  //Do Something
}
```

Comment: This is by far the best and to the point solution I have come across. The main reason for this is nobody except a developer is going to switch browser width to test responsive behavior! A site user will use one device at a time, either a desktop or a tablet or a handheld. I presume this solution was suggested keeping above in mind!

Comment: You will still get users changing the browser side, eg dragging it to a second screen or changing its size so they can see windows underneath and other user cases.. But its a simple example which simply reminds people.. Check the width..

Comment: Great answer!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 version:

```
function findBootstrapEnvironment() {
    var envs = ["sm", "md", "lg", "xl"];
    var env = "";

    var $el = $("<div>");
    $el.appendTo($("body"));
    $el.addClass("d-block");
    for (var i = envs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        env = envs[i];
        $el.addClass("d-" + env + "-none");
        if ($el.is(":hidden")) {
            $el.remove();
            return env;
        }
    }
    $el.remove();
    return "xs";    //extra small
}
```