# Bootstrap - Dynamic height sizing on buttons and text fields, for each environment

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 to create some HTML responsive forms, and there's one thing I'm trying to do, about layout.

I want to change dynamically the height of buttons and text fields by following these rules:

1. On desktop devices, use small buttons / text fields
2. On mobile devices, use large buttons / text fields

I know that I can do it by using [these button](http://getbootstrap.com/css/?#buttons-sizes) and [text field](http://getbootstrap.com/css/?#forms-controls-sizes) classes. But, I want to use these classes only if user is accessing the page from a mobile device, not always.

I know, too,  that you can show/hide HTML elements by using [these classes from Bootstrap Responsive Utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities), but I need to give an id to all buttons / text fields, so I don't know if I can duplicate these elements and wrap each of then inside a div that will be shown on a specific environment, since two elements with the same id is wrong by HTML specifications.

I tried an approach based on [that solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462672/jquery-detect-bootstrap-3-state#answer-19462847), and I simply add/remove these classes based on each state/environment. It's working, but is there an easier approach to this?

Answer (score 2):

To change specific element style by screen size you can use media queries. for example:

```
<button class="btn dynamic-button">
```

css:

```
@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
    .dynamic-button {
        height: 20px;    
    }
}
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max) {
    .dynamic-button {
        height: 40px;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this pure CSS? Or LESS / SASS?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't LESS? Because I tried that and it didn't worked. It seems to me that @screen-xs-max is a LESS variable, and I don't want to convert my CSS to LESS for now. However, I tried the approach from this link and it worked: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive. It basically changed the LESS variable to values in pixels.